# How to prevent a folder and its content from being deleted?

Tags: android, shell, symlink

I have created a symlink to make an application load it files from a shared folder

Its working correctly, when i uninstall the application it delete all files in the folder, how could i stop the files from getting deleted?

I tried calling chmod -R 777 in the top folder but it still deleting the files

```
adb shell 
ln -s /mnt/shared/<package name> /data/media/0/Android/data
chmod -R 777 /data/media/0/Android/data/<package name>
```

Comment: Well, 777 gives all permission, and doing this recursively allows anyone to do anything (deletion, modification) to everything below your package folder. What's the point? If you want to prevent changes, you have to take away permissions, not to grant them!

Comment: @user1934428 which value them?

Comment: In order to delete a file, the write-permission of the directory the file is in, is needed. Hence, `chmod a-w DIR` would remove delete permission for the directory (read `a-w` as _all have no right to write_). However the file itself can still be modified. If you want to disallow this too, you would have tor remove delete permissions for the file as well.

Comment: chmod -R a-w worked, ty